# Как использовать google sign-in чтобы пройти авторизацию на google spreadsheets в telegram боте с телефона?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, google-spreadsheet

У меня есть простой телеграм-бот который позволяет просматривать и добавлять данные в определенную гугл-таблицу. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы авторизация происходила на том устройстве, на котором я его запускаю. Т.е. т.к. это телеграм бот, то я могу его использовать и с помощью телефона, но в таком случае авторизировать (т.е. дать доступ моему приложению вносить изменения в гугл-таблицу) я могу только с помощью ПК. Хотелось бы узнать есть ли вообще возможность это обойти? Возможно нужно использовать интеграцию google sign-in, но как это сделать я не знаю.

На всякий случай даю код:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Quickstart {

    /**
     * Application name.
     */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
            "Google Sheets API Java ua.telegrambot.movies.services.Quickstart";

    /**
     * Directory to store user credentials for this application.
     */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart");

    /**
     * Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}.
     */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /**
     * Global instance of the JSON factory.
     */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
            JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /**
     * Global instance of the HTTP transport.
     */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * <p>
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
                Quickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Sheets API client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized Sheets API client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static List<List<Object>> getSpreadSheetRecords(String spreadsheetId, String range) throws IOException {
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();
        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values != null && values.size() != 0) {
            return values;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void appendNewSheetRecords(String spreadsheetId, String range, List<List<Object>> values) throws IOException {
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();
        ValueRange body = new ValueRange()
                .setValues(values);
//        UpdateValuesResponse result =
//                service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, range, body)
//                        .setValueInputOption("RAW")
//                        .execute();
        AppendValuesResponse appendResult = service.spreadsheets().values()
                .append(spreadsheetId, range, body)
                .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
                .setInsertDataOption("INSERT_ROWS")
                .setIncludeValuesInResponse(true)
                .execute();

        ValueRange total = appendResult.getUpdates().getUpdatedData();
        System.out.println(total);
    }

}
```